# (How) does On-Behalf-Of authentication flow work with Azure App Service Managed Identities?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I'm looking into securing both my Web Application and Web API running on Azure, using Azure Managed Service Identities.

However, I am wondering if the *On-behalf-of* authentication flow works in this case?
I can't find any clear documentation on either answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OBO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) using [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) is not supported.

Comment: Where can I verify this claim?